# Kohana 3.x auth

Tags: php, kohana

Where is the official kohana 3.x documentation? Whenever I go there now it's just blank pages  http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/auth

I'm looking around for a good Kohana 3.x auth documentation, if anyone knows anything about it, please share with me.

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is still at [here](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/).  However the documentation for the Auth module is not enabled there.  Even if it were, the Auth docs are currently just stubs.  You can see them at [here](https://github.com/kohana/auth/tree/3.1%2Fmaster/guide/auth) or in your own Kohana install by enabling the userguide module.  Right now you are probably best off following the examples in the Kerkness [wiki](http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php) until the official documentation has been worked on.